# How to avoid uploading duplicated row into BigQuery table with Google App Script

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm uploading some data into BigQuery from a google sheet using Google App Script. Is there a way to upload these data without uploading duplicated row...

Here is the JobSpec I'm currently using :

```
var jobSpec = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: 'ClientAccount',
          tableId: tableId
        },
        allowJaggedRows: true,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
        schema: {
          fields: [
        {name: 'date', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'Impressions', type: 'INTEGER'},
        {name: 'Clicks', type: 'INTEGER'},
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

So I'm looking for something like `allowDuplicates: true`... I think you get the idea... I can I do this...

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery loads do not have any concept of deduplication, but you can effectively do this by loading all the data to an initial table, then querying that table with a deduplication query into another table.

```
with t as (SELECT 1 as field, [1,3,4, 4] as dupe) 
SELECT ANY_VALUE(field), dupe FROM t, t.dupe group by dupe;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deduplicate your data with Apps Script directly in Google Sheets before loading to BQ.

Or as Victor said you can deduplicate your data into BQ. With smth like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field_to_deduplicate ORDER BY key) AS RowNr
  FROM
    YourDataset.YourTable ) AS X
WHERE
  X.RowNr = 1
```